# SSRS 2008 - How to add a subtotal to a matrix

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, matrix, ssrs-2008, subtotal

How do I add a subtotal to a matrix in reporting services 2008?  If I right click on a cell I see an option to add a total but no subtotal.

(I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I've looked everywhere.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I think I figured it out.  You have to right-click the group and select add total.

I was confused because the total was for the group I clicked instead of totaling that group's children.

I was also getting all 0's for the totals, but it turns out that's what my data summed up to.